# SQL Server selecting a string from table using in clause

Tags: sql-server, string, where-in

I'm having a strange SQL Server issue.

Using the following query:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id IN ('id1', 'id2', .......)
```

when id is nchar(30) and 'id1','id2' are values, I get a result which isn't in the values I entered.

Is it possible that SQL Server is searching for a string contained in the values?

## Added

query:

```
SELECT Word FROM WordDictionary WHERE Word IN ('DESPERADO', 'WWW.MYSAVINGS.COM', 'RELIED', 'GALS/GUYS....U', 'MISSOULA', 'STARING...WHY', 'OHIO,,,WHAT', 'ALEYO"MEANS', 'EXCRETE', 'POETERS', 'REMOVAL?IF', 'MOTOT', 'VIEW/SOUND', 'SCHOLD', 'FLINGS', '300000', 'BIGBANG', 'INVOKE', 'COMPLIER', 'UPNISHAD', 'FLUFF/LINT', 'DONATED?..PLEASE', 'EPHEDRINE', 'AGAIN-', 'WHUNT', 'LEVE', 'ARIEL', 'SEIZURES,AND', 'ANYON', 'WELL~AS', 'GGGGGGGGOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOODDDDD', 'ALGERIA', 'LONDON...CAN', 'TWAIN''S', 'BUTIFUL', 'CIRRHIOSIS', 'PHP-NUKE', 'SCREWD', 'RECONNECT', 'BAND...''SIGUR', 'ROS''', 'DEFLEPOARD', 'FIHGT', 'DRE''S', 'ACQUAINTED', '77067', 'INCREASE/DECREASE', 'AWHILE..SHOULD', 'BABY???..MORE', 'CHRISTEN', 'SUNSLIFE', 'HYANCINTHS', 'NOVEMEBER', 'IEEE', 'IRENE', '5"4', 'BAYSIDE', 'DOJO', 'PEOPLES::DO', 'INFORMATION/ANSWER', 'BLACKWORM', 'MYWIFE.D', '42D', 'COLONEL', 'ESCAPES', 'KW', 'WASH/CLENSE', 'ENCOURAGES', 'HOLINESS', '4710', 'MONOATOMIC', 'FORM-', 'NAVIGATIONS', 'ASHLIEY(TWINS', 'ALIAS....WHAT', 'MARIOKART', 'HORNYNESS', 'CONVERSIONS', 'NUIT', 'PARISTEL:0660442290PL06', 'PUSSY', 'WILLOWS', 'BOYFRIEND/BABYDADDY', 'PARASITES', 'TABOILD', 'J.T', 'TERESEA', '---FREE---', 'KAMORA', 'SIMONS', 'FORSYTHIA', 'RAZORTHOUGHT', 'ABSINTHE', '9-3', 'BAIT-CASTING', 'CUMULATIVE', 'HELP>>>', 'MATZO', 'LIMOSINE', 'SCD353', 'BANGARAM', 'BRUNEL', 'KWTV878', 'NEAPOLITAN', 'OFYOUR', '2SIN', '²', '3SINX', 'IMPERFECTION', 'NONBELIEF', 'FLEM', 'NON-ADJACENT', 'WASHINGTION', 'WHERE/IF', 'BRONTE''S', 'WUTHERING', 'SOMEONE/A', 'TEAM.WHAT', 'PRESIDENT,WHEN', 'DIRICHLET', 'X-AND', 'Y-INTERCEPTS', 'STAMPED', 'PROCRDURE', 'AK32', '*67', 'HANUKKAH', 'MONIE', 'TAGAYTAY', 'NATURES', 'HASS', 'TORMENTS', 'PROPOTIONAL', 'SUDERLAND', 'CONROL', 'CONSEQUENCE', 'SAW?YOU', 'WITHDREW', 'PMT', 'JAIL?WAT', 'DEFFEND', '-12>8X', '4X>6', 'MX-C550', '6-DISC', 'SVQ3', 'BULLSHITING', 'PWEAZE', '23SECONDS', 'VISHWANATHAN''S', 'INTERNALIZING', 'MCCAFFERTY''S', 'TODAY...AND', 'CHANCE....WOULD', 'DEC.''41', '''45', 'HAILLE', 'SELASSIE', 'OF...GREENDAY', 'DEAD/ARMY', 'EX-NFL', 'JACKSONVILLE,FL', 'ATLANTA,HOUSTON,OR', 'ECCENTRICITY', 'CONIC', 'XXX@YAHOO.CO.UK', 'XXX@YAHOO.COM', 'DISCRET', '_______', 'ROMACE', 'SUBCATEGORY', 'REDUDUCE', 'EXERCISER', 'MUNITE', 'MESSENGER.SO', 'NIGEL', 'PLANER', 'QUESTION?31576*66496139', 'KODJOE', '919', '1847', 'D.WADE', 'HUMAN''S', 'MULTI-NATIONAL', 'GOGGLE', 'GAAP', 'CONFUSED.IONT', 'ST8', 'ROOM/HOME', 'BOLB', 'GRANDMA-', 'PARSON', 'BELIZE', 'UNITY', 'AWARDS''', 'TOGHTHER', 'LONDON+GREATER', 'JERSEY...IE', 'NETGAR', 'NBC,ABC', 'CONON', 'RECIDENT', 'CANCERS', 'PITTSBURGH/INDY', 'CREATETH', 'MUSICAL''S', 'HEELLLLPPPP', 'MASRER', 'NAME,AND', 'ANAEROBIC', 'SPACIAL', 'SPOUSE/SIGNIFICANT', 'TRIGNOCEPHALY', 'RAW''S', 'BLOGGIN', '9.2', 'FLATTENING', 'FLOWER,ANIMALAND', 'EXPRESSES', 'FRDS', 'NOT?PLS', 'CLEARIFY', 'CLEARFIELD/JEFFERSON', 'HACE', 'FELICIANO', 'MEDICINE--THEY', 'DASCHUND', 'PLINTER', 'SKETCHY', 'I..WHAT', 'JUVENTINA', 'SOMUCH', 'SHEEN', 'HALEX', '11-IN-1', 'URBANIZATION', 'WILWOOD', 'CALIPER', 'NERVE-RACKING', 'OBSESESSION', 'EZRA', 'TALBOT', 'SHOCKWAVE', 'PASCO', '300$-600$', '108,000', '*BOYZ', 'ONLY*PLZ', 'INTERNET)CAN', 'CONCISE', 'TOP40', 'HICUPPS', '4:00', 'OPOSITE', 'NETWORKER?=', 'Q-LINK', 'HSG', 'AMINE', 'RIGHTS,,HOW', 'EMILIANO', 'PEDREGON', 'DILEMA', 'GROUPTHINK', 'MONTEAL', '17...&', '13:04', 'NASHIK', 'NOBIA', 'LINEWIRE', 'ISOCKS', 'DAY........WAIT', 'KATY', 'BODERLINE', 'CONNORS', 'WHWRE', 'CROMWELL', 'COE', '1+1=', 'UMMM.....WHATS', 'BOND''S', 'VIEWLOADER', 'MAXIS', 'MAT_LOVE83@YAHOO.COM', 'SCISSORS', 'UNSANITARY', 'KANSANS', 'SALINA', '''ARENA''', '''CAROLINA''', 'BIOMAGNIFICATION', 'BIOASSIMILATION', 'WOMBATS', 'POOS', 'ARSES', 'SOCIALIZATION', 'GROUPS,RACES', 'FULL-BLOOD', 'TASMANIAN', 'INCLINE', 'PICA', 'FIGGERED', '9.HE', 'RETINOBLASTOMA,IS', 'COAT''S', '2MOWRO', 'DOTHAN', 'DIFRNT', 'DEPICTS', 'WHAK', 'NETHERLAND', 'FORTHE', 'OFMICROSOFT', 'INDIGO', 'I-MAC', 'SHANGHAINESE', 'DINOSAOUR', 'SUBCAMPS', 'CARDINAL', 'NEBRASKA''S', 'KOMO', 'PIRATE/SAILING', 'ZOPICLONE', 'CRYPTIC', 'CLUE"COULD', 'WHEELCHAIR,NO', 'OVERWIEGHT.DOES', 'ALL..MY', 'BOYFRIIEND', 'MAGTECH', 'TROUBLES...ANY', 'BACK,REDUCED', 'JEWELY', 'CRAFTSMEN''S', 'HAUNTER', 'GENGAR', 'CRYSTAL.WHERE', 'LAHORE', 'SANDLER''S', 'ACCENT...WHAT', 'WOOOOOAAAAAAAAH', 'W''T', 'RAJASEKARAN_NIKIL@YAHOO.COM', 'SPEICES', 'MCFLY', 'BIOCONVERSION', 'GUERRERO', 'CATHOLICS......WHAT', 'NOV.1--', 'ECONOLINE', 'AMOVIE', 'COUNSELLING', 'HANDSPAN', 'ATTIUTE', 'HAIR??HELP', 'PLASTIC?CERAMIC', 'TITLEIST', 'REISDENTS', '7''S', 'FERMATS', 'JBW&CWW', 'RB''S', 'KENYON', 'BAPTIST''S', 'THUMPERS', 'THOZ', 'HATZ', 'MSNISMS', 'POLL/SURVEY', 'INFUSION', 'FUNDRAISER', 'PROTECTS', 'ANTOINO', 'SYALLBUS', 'GCSES', 'SPIDER,SNAKE,DOG,CAT', 'KNOW.PLEASE', 'CHACH', 'DISSAPIONTED', 'TODGER', 'SH*TTING', 'LODESTONE', 'SARBANES', 'OXLEY', 'ANOTHR', 'RELATIONSHIP????HOW', 'T9', 'JIGGLY', 'GOOD?IS', 'HARDEN', 'DESERT?I', 'SIGNIFANT', 'WEDO', 'SCHAT', 'LQ', 'TENCHI', 'ME...WHAT''S', 'ERUPTED', '£40', '£150', 'UPGRATE', 'I500', '2003SE', 'PROMOT', 'SALUTES', 'GRAEME', 'SOUNESS', 'SERRONE', 'AHAVE', 'BUSTSA', 'IMPARTIAL', 'SUGARCULT', 'RFID', 'SWIPE', '30X', 'HOUSE''S', 'BI-WAY', 'BLYTHE,CA', 'REDDER', 'PLUMPER', 'LEFTWINGERS', 'WHINGE', 'ANNOYING..!!1', 'SENSORY', 'ADHD/ODD', 'ZYBAN', 'RAMP', 'SUB-WOOFER''S', 'TATTOOIST', '477', 'SOFISTCATED', 'B/J', 'ALLURE', 'THIS?(SEE', 'PAKISTANIS:DO', 'PLEASE?I', 'CLASHING', 'KNOW(DOCS', 'WHITESMOKE', 'SCREEN''S', 'SPINK', 'YOUI', 'DELICATE', 'MISDIAGNOSED', 'DIPERNO', 'HIM.PLEASE', '45CM', '35CM', 'ENOUGHT', 'DECIMETERS?PUT', 'RDMB', 'HOMELOANS', 'HAA', 'ORIGIANL', 'RESTON', 'ZINNIAS', 'PERENNIAL', 'WHOOPIE', 'CUSHIONS', 'POOFS', 'CAT,ITS', 'TIME,ITS', 'TUXEDOS', 'CHICKAN', 'WHISLE', 'RUMBLING', '7LEVELS', 'YOUFROM', 'CEMO', 'RECURRENT', 'LARYNGEAL', 'W/NO', 'SOUCRE', 'COMMA', 'WORDCUB', 'WOMEN:HAVE', 'PIGGYBACK', 'ANOLE', 'CHRISTIANSEN', 'SWEEPSTAKES,GETTING', 'WON.HOW', 'EUDORA5.1', 'EXPRESS,NETSCAPE4.X', '6.X', '''COURT', 'WISK''', '4/13', '50-70', 'DAUGHTER,CAN', 'UVULA', '''AYURVEDA''', 'ACUPUNTURE', 'BAJA', 'REASONIBLE', 'PUZZY', 'SORCERER', 'DISEASES/SICKNESS', 'ANUS/RECTUM?CAN', 'HOME?WHAT', 'COCETH', 'KELLOGGS', 'DAISUKE')
```

result:

```
2
```

## Added

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordDictionary](
[Word] [nchar](30) NOT NULL,
[Count] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_WordDictionary] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
      [Word] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: What is your exact query and exact result?

Comment: @Martin added query and result.

Comment: Is this in management studio? does a smaller set of values in the IN () produce the same result?

Comment: Strange. I can't reproduce if I try `WITH WordDictionary(Word) AS
(SELECT CAST(2 AS NCHAR(30)))` then your query. Can you cast the `2` result value to `binary(60)` and post the result?

Comment: @Martin 0x320020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000

Comment: @Noam - Can you identify the specific item in the `in` list that causes this to appear? Does it happen if you just try `WHERE Word IN ('9.2')`?

Comment: @Noam - What collation are you on? I reckon `'²'` is causing the issue (though it doesn't match under my collation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `IN` list contains the item `'²'`.

I'll be very surprised if that isn't the source of the issue (though it doesn't actually match for me under my default collation)

Comment: BTW what collation are you using? maybe the collation im using isnt fitting

Comment: I'm on `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` which apparently doesn't treat those as equal. However `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` does. You probably don't want to treat them as separate words though just as one is superscript?

Comment: Confirmed on my installation. `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS` results in a match between `'2'` and `'²'` while `COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN` does not result in a match.

Comment: Never really thought about case sensitivity applying to numbers before!

Comment: @Martin Strangely also on SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS i get same result.

Comment: @Noam - What if you try `WHERE Word COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS IN ('²')`

Comment: @Martin my mistake i changed DB Collation but not column collation
I wonder if it wasn't a PK would the change take effect recursively

Answer (score 1):

Try making the strings in the IN() clause Unicode by prefixing with N

```
IN (N'Id1', N'Id2',...)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, SQL Server would respond as you and I are both expecting. So I knocked up a little test example. and sure enough, I got only the results expected.

With it being a text column, using LIKE/BETWEEN and other similar clauses can cause problems if you are not careful, but WHERE IN should be fairly clear cut.

I suggest you post some DDL + DML that includes both the 'good' and the unexpected results. In theory, you are doing the right thing, but until we see what you are working with, we won't be able to spot the 'gotcha'.

Comment: I didnt completely got what you meant with post some DDL + DML...
But ill try to clearfy how i got to the results i did:
I created a dictonery of words and their appreances in a DB.
but in some point inserting i got somehow an excption of PK vailotion. There for im trying to get the words wich are duplicated using this query.

Comment: DDL = Data Description Language (i.e. the CREATE TABLE that you have now added) and DML = Data Manipulation Language (i.e. some INSERT statements to recreate some of your data). With these, we can recreate a version of your DB and try for ourselves.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from test 
where data IN ('Aa' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, 'Ab' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
```